# Why is Sun inventing another module system when everyone has standardised on OSGi?

Tags: java, module, osgi, java-platform-module-system

Sun is putting a lot of effort behind modularising the JDK in the form of [Jigsaw](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/), and insinuating that it should be the module format of choice for other Java developers as well. The only notable player who is using this is NetBeans (and derivative applications).

On the other hand, the industry has standardised around OSGi, with all of the major application vendors basing their runtimes on the module platform, even Sun's own Glassfish. There's even a port of NetBeans to use OSGi as the module system instead of NetBeans own modules. Even Maven is working towards becoming an OSGi runtime.

Is it just NIH, licensing, or another reason?

Comment: Do you have a reference for the "insinuating that it should ..." part of your question? The page you link has the tone of a research project's homepage, not that used to introduce a key technology that Sun wants everyone to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excellent question. My understanding is that in some areas OSGi goes way beyond that which is necessary for JVM modules (with all the corresponding complexity that brings) whilst in other areas it doesn't go far enough. So there's a lot of overlap between them but perhaps not enough.

[See this blog entry](http://altair.cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/jsr294-modularity-eg/2009-November/000390.html)

Answer (score 8):

Citing http://blogs.oracle.com/mr/entry/jigsaw:

> OSGi is not at all integrated with the
>   Java language, however, having been
>   built atop the Java SE Platform rather
>   than from within it.
>
> This last problem can be ﬁxed. Sun
>   plans now to work directly with the
>   OSGi Alliance so that a future version
>   of the OSGi Framework may fully
>   leverage the features of JSR 294 and
>   thereby achieve tighter integration
>   with the language.
>
> (...)
>
> If and when a future version of the
>   Java SE Platform includes a speciﬁc
>   module system then Sun will provide a
>   means to migrate Jigsaw modules up to
>   that standard. In the meantime we’ll
>   actively seek ways in which to
>   interoperate with other module
>   systems, and in particular with OSGi.

Comment: Ah, that's the blog entry I was looking for and couldn't find :)

Comment: The problem is that that isn't happening. JSR294 is effectively dead, and has no bearing on Jigsaw (or vice versa). Whether the module keyword can end up being used is somewhat orthogonal to the problem of a module system itself.

Comment: @AlBlue - the status of JSR294 confuses me, too. The JCP page lists it as inactive, but work is (apparently) continuing as part of Jigsaw. I think you are mistaken about them being unrelated. The Jigsaw page says: __Relationship to JSR 294__ _Working documents posted here should be considered as drafts of material subject to further discussion within that EG._ http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/

Comment: There's a difference to what the Jigsaw page says and what the 294 group is (supposed to be) working on. It looks like Sun are giving up on the JSR and just doing their own thing; the mailing list is dead as a dodo and the last message says 'Go and discuss Jigsaw on the Jigsaw mailing list'.

Answer (score 5):

The rationale behind project Jigsaw and how it relates to OSGi was outlined by the Jigsaw team in [Java Posse Podcast 259](http://www.javaposse.com/index.php?post_id=492239).

These projects do not entirely overlap and the introduction of Jigsaw does not sound the death knell for OSGi - the scope of OSGi goes beyond anything Jigsaw will attempt. There's much more to Jigsaw than the OSGi team is in a position to provide (language, class and JVM implementation changes). The design of OSGi is based on the current JVM design - the changes to the JVM will benefit everyone.

At least, that is my take from [what I've read](http://www.osgi.org/blog/2009/08/simple-module-system.html).

Answer (score 1):

One feature is **missing in OSGi**. It does **not support modules that are subsets of packages**. The [export is done on the package level](http://www.osgi.org/blog/2007/04/importance-of-exporting-nd-importing.html).

Package subset modules are the only way to cut the Gordian knot of JDK dependencies. And a nice hint why you should keep your code clean of **circular dependencies**.

> [Over the years, however, this style
>   of development can lead to unexpected
>   connections between APIs—and between
>   their implementations—leading in turn
>   to increased startup time and memory
>   footprint. A trivial command-line
>   “Hello, world!” program, e.g., now
>   loads and initializes over 300
>   separate classes, taking around 100ms
>   on a recent desktop machine despite
>   yet more heroic engineering efforts
>   such as class-data sharing. The
>   situation is even worse, of course,
>   for larger applications.](http://blogs.oracle.com/mr/entry/massive_monolithic_jdk)

Edit: I was **wrong**. [OSGi does support split packages](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/07/14/why-i-cant-recommend-using-import-package/).

Comment: I hadn't come across the concept of package subset modules - do you know of any blogs or articles that discuss this?

Comment: "4. It must be possible for different types in a single Java package to
belong to different modules." http://altair.cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/jsr294-modularity-observer/2009-January/000002.html

Comment: As the edit suggests, this is wrong. In fact, Harmony, an open-source JVM, already uses OSGi manifests to represent breaks between modules, including those with a Geordian knot.

Comment: I'd say split packages are a bug, not a feature. Of course, the way the JDK API have evolved, you need to support them if you want to avoid a major (incompatible) refactoring. But if someone were to design the java.* packages from scratch, I suppose she would align packages along module boundaries.

Comment: Is it possible that subset packages means to only export some but not all classes within a package that one wishes to export ?

Comment: When you export only parts of your packages that is a regular module. With split package modules you can have multiple modules per package.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the JavaPosse [interview with Mark Reinhold](http://www.javaposse.com/index.php?post_id=492239) on the subject.