# How to simply control module dependencies in Java SE

Tags: java, components, dependencies

I am working on a Java SE project that has both a library part (a few packages of `public` classes) intended to be used by programs written by others and an applications part (classes with `main()` methods) that use that library. So the installation evironment must handle the possibility of there being multiple applications programs simultaneously present and using **different** versions of the library. Any ideas on how to handle this? How do people avoid [JAR hell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373193/what-is-classpath-hell-and-is-was-it-really-a-problem-for-java)?

A future version of Java will incorporate the [Jigsaw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858953/why-is-sun-inventing-another-module-system-when-everyone-has-standardised-on-osgi) functionality. Enterprise applications can make use of the [OSGi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106222/what-does-osgi-solve) component functionality. But what about *non Enterprise* applications *now*? Is there anything simpler than OSGi that gets the job done?

---

**Edit, after some preliminary answers:**
I can handle the build-time dependency problem reasonably well using our version control and build process. Its help with the run-time dependency problem I'm really interested in.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139534/classloader-issues-how-to-determine-which-library-versions-jar-files-are-load/139796#139796

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Sure: [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/)</s>

Sorry, misread the question.

You can use OSGi (Equinox or Felix) in any application, it doesn't have to be an enterprise (server based) application.

That said, you can easily control the visibility of your classes yourself by creating `URLClassLoader`s as needed. That's how the OSGi implementations do it.

Comment: Maven isn't a run-time tool is it? Not in the same way that OSGi is for constructing an application from plugins, and resolving runtime dependencies based on version information etc. My understanding is that Maven is a development tool rather than a runtime facility like OSGi. Mind you, I never really have understood Maven :-)

Comment: You can use `mvn dependency:copy` to create a copy of all dependencies in some directory. So in your IDE, you use Maven to build the compile time classpath and then the dependency plugin to build a deployable. Or you can use the assembly plugin to create one big JAR.

Comment: Writing your own class loader? That sounds rather complicated.

Comment: No, just call `new URLClassLoader(urls, getClass().getClassLoader())` and add the *additional* JARs that should be visible in this classloader to `urls`. The new classloader will ask the parent classloader for any unknown classes. Now you can load classes from it via `loadclass()` and use reflection to create instances and invoke methods. The setup takes a bit effort but afterwards, it's normal Java code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558720/when-should-i-use-a-platform-like-osgi-and-when-it-must-be-avoided suggests OSGi is suitable for mostly for long runing (server)applications.

Comment: @Raedwald: It's most often used that way but that doesn't mean it's limited in any way for desktop apps.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) is a light-weight solution. It does *only* dependency management and doesn't try to change your build system to match.

Comment: Apache Ivy seems to does build-time dependency management. Does it also do run-time dependency management?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/).

> Apache Maven is a software project management and comprehension tool. Based on the concept of a project object model (POM), Maven can manage a project's build, reporting and documentation from a central piece of information.

Comment: While I really like Maven and use it a lot, it should be said that Maven provides a lot more than just dependency management. It also provides a build system and is pretty opinionated about project structure and hierarchies (which can make it hard to convert existing projects).

Comment: @Joachim , Somehow disagree. I find maven's dir structure very good to convert existing project to maven one. also depends on the project size and structure. but its not that hard I feel

Comment: it's not the structure that's hard to convert, but if you've got existing (complex) build systems in place, then switching over to Maven "just" to get dependency/library management can be costly. In my opinion that cost can easily pay of in the long run, but the cost *does* exist and can be quite high.

Comment: Maven is a build tool. The question is not about build. Maven does nothing to address the question.

Comment: @Tom maven't isn't simply  build tool, it is project management tool.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is dependency resolution, then [Apache Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) fits the bill. It performs similarly to Maven's dependency resolution, but lacks Maven's complexity since it has much fewer features.

Comment: Apache Ivy seems to does build-time dependency management. Does it also do run-time dependency management?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that I've ever heard the term "runtime dependency" used in a Java context. Runtime dependencies, as I'm familiar with, are usually handled through application context. The [Spring Framework](http://www.springsource.org/) is one such way to manage application context.